# Foundation menu overflowing off of mobile

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am working on a redesign of a website, and I used the foundation framework to help make it responsive. Everything is working great, however the menu when made mobile sized, is overflowing off the side of the page. Attached is the html & css, any help would be appreciated!

HTML

```
 <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
    <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>

            <!-- PUT LOGO HERE PLS -->
            <li class="menu-text site-title">
                <a href="index.html"> <img src="img/logosean.png" alt="teddy bear head"> Teddy Bear Wheelchair Foundation</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- NOT DOWN HERE SILLY, UP THERE -->

    </div>
    <div class="top-bar-right">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="navPush"><a href="help.html">Who We Help</a></li>
            <li class="navPush"><a href="aboutus.html">About</a></li>
            <li class="navPush"><a href="contribute.html">Contribute</a></li>
            <li class="navPush"><a href="partners.html">Partners</a></li>
            <li class="navPush"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.top-bar,
.top-bar ul {
  background-color: #4c1a1b;
  font-family: "Lato", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fcfae1;
}

.top-bar ul a {
  color: #fcfae1;
  list-style: none;
}

.navPush {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.top-bar ul a:hover {
  color: #f6e497;
}

.site-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: inherit;
}
```

[Text Cutting Off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h76Ua.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class `menu` in `ul` which has predefined properties

```
.menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
 }
```

Therefore, in your CSS, write:

```
.menu > li{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

or else change the menu class.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! This has been bugging me for a while, really appreciate it